# How to change my Service Reference of WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

My actual service reference is this:

```
http://localhost:2937/PlayerService.svc
```

Both programs (client and server) are running in my machine.
How can I change to access by internet? I tried to put my IP in localhost, but didn't find the address.

Comment: Are you hosting it in the Visual Studio Development web server (Cassini)? If so, you need to deploy it to a real IIS web server before you will be able to access it from another machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give us way more details about your problem. My guess is that you're hosting it in the Visual Studio Development web server (Cassini). You need to deploy it to a real IIS web server before you can access it from another machine.

Comment: that shouldn't be that hard =/

Comment: @Alan It isn't that hard - you can run it from IIS on your local machine, just not from the VS dev server.